# Renaming default Cocoapods project

Tags: cocoapods

Is it possible to rename the default Pods xcodeproj and Pods subdirectory that are generated when you run pod install? Is there any way in the Podfile or pass an argument to `pod install` to do this? I couldn't find anything that suggested this on the http://cocoapods.org documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently an option of any kind in CocoaPods. If you would like to see this in a future version we gladly accept pull requests over on [Github](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll need to brush up on my Ruby skills before I can contribute :) Just to let you know, the reason I wanted this feature is that I have multiple xcodeprojs in a workspace and a few of these projects have their own Podfiles. I wanted to have the Pods projects for each xcodeproj included in the one workspace, so remaning them for each project I thought might be useful.